# Send data from PC to RPi although theyre not in the same LAN

Tags: server, java, data-transfer, database, sendemail

i'm planning a school project that should represent a 
two-factor authentication. I already made a user interface to type in information to log in like email address and password.
 My plan was to encrypt the information, send it to the RPi, decrypt it and compare it to a database where every information of different users is saved. After that the RPi should send an email to the user with a verification code.
 My problem is that i'm at school when i present it and my RPi is at home.
Whats the best way to send my information to the RPi in my case?
I only have one RPi so it all should work on only one RPi. Also im only good at Java and never dealt with syntax of other programming languages.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Will your teacher let you take the Pi to school with you for the demo?  Can you attach it to a wired port since schools often lock down wireless? (It is possible to "open up a port" on your home router, but that can be very dangerous, and I recommend against it.)

Comment: I guess he would let me do so, but i think it isnt that complex when my pc and the RPi are in the same LAN, is it?

Comment: How complex it is depends on what you're doing.  Get it working at home, then take the whole thing to school.

Comment: Do you have any advice how to setup this whole server thing? So that i can send email, save information in a database and manage communication with clients all with the same RPi?

Comment: We'll get our fingers spanked if we engage in a lengthy conversation here.  The format on Stack Exchange is one question and one answer; the end.  However, Google is your friend.  Try "Raspberry Pi send email" and then "Raspberry Pi database," and so on.

Comment: At the risk of getting in trouble for continuing with this, you can run Apache3, MariaDB, and PHP on your Pi.  That will get you a web server interface, database, and PHP as a "glue" language.  You'll need to add email, which won't be hard with PHP.  Concerning encrypting passwords, read this, and don't forget to credit your source: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: Hello and welcome -- You must set a static IP address for the home internet. Tell it to the ISP. Then, you have a stable static IP address over the internet. Next, you need to set DMZ on your home modem to forward incoming packets to the local IP address of raspberry pi. So, you can access to the raspberry pi from the internet all over the world. Take care about the security of that, change default pass, etc because it's gonna work over the internet and it's easy to hack, BTW. However, next, Ask a question on Stackoverflow for getting an idea about implementing this in Java, not gonna be hard.

Comment: @M.Rostami - `Next, you need to set DMZ on your home modem to forward incoming packets to the local IP address of raspberry pi.` - or simple port forwarding, rather than open the pi completely to the interwebs